# AngularJS 2 hidden location strategy back navigation

Tags: typescript, angular

I have implemented a simple `LocationStrategy` which disables the browser location bar changes used by the other stock strategies. I want to create several smaller apps which are to be plugged in into arbitrary web pages where the browser location must not be touched, though some kind of navigation is required. This works rather well with the new strategy. The only thing missing now is a `back()`-function for navigation. Obviously I can't call `window.back()` anymore but I also did not find any internal method to call by reading the angular sources. I guess I could call `LocationStrategy.back()` directly but then I still need some way to make the router update the current view. Is there some event I could fire or something else to archive a view update?

This is the current implementation of my location strategy:

```
import { Injectable, Inject, Optional, platform } from 'angular2/core';
import { LocationStrategy, PlatformLocation, APP_BASE_HREF, } from 'angular2/router';
import { joinWithSlash, normalizeQueryParams } from 'angular2/src/router/location_strategy';
import { UrlChangeListener } from 'angular2/src/router/location/platform_location';
import { isPresent } from 'angular2/src/facade/lang';

@Injectable()
export class HiddenLocationStrategy extends LocationStrategy {
    private _baseHref: string = '';
    private pathHistory: string[] = [];
    private poppedPathHistory: string[] = [];
    constructor(private _platformLocation: PlatformLocation,
        @Optional() @Inject(APP_BASE_HREF) _baseHref?: string) {
        super();
        if (isPresent(_baseHref)) {
            this._baseHref = _baseHref;
        }
    }

    onPopState(fn: UrlChangeListener): void {
    }

    getBaseHref(): string { return this._baseHref }

    path(): string {
        return this.pathHistory.length > 0 ? this.pathHistory[this.pathHistory.length - 1] : '';
    }

    prepareExternalUrl(internal: string): string {
        var url = joinWithSlash(this._baseHref, internal);
        return url;
    }

    pushState(state: any, title: string, path: string, queryParams: string) {
        this.pathHistory.push(path);
    }

    replaceState(state: any, title: string, path: string, queryParams: string) {
    }

    forward(): void { this.pathHistory.push(this.poppedPathHistory.pop()); }

    back(): void { this.poppedPathHistory.push(this.pathHistory.pop()); }
}
```

Comment: The way to activate the `HashLocationStrategy` is to include the `{ useHash: true }` argument when bootstrapping the routing module. But how did you activate this custom location strategy?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to provide a custom `PlatformLocation` https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/platform/browser/location/platform_location.ts and call its `forward()` and `back()` methods.

The

```
abstract onPopState(fn: UrlChangeListener): void;
abstract onHashChange(fn: UrlChangeListener): void;
```

seem the events the router subscribes to.

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate is

Answer (score 0):

The solution involves leveraging the `history.pushState` API by putting logic in the `pushState` method to record an incrementing identifier (along with any other state that you want) and logic in the `onPopState` method to evaluate whether the popped state is a back navigation or a forward navigation and finally by wrapping several of `PlatformLocation`'s method.

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF, LocationStrategy, PlatformLocation, Location, LocationChangeListener } from '@angular/common';
import { Inject, Injectable, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { isPresent } from '@angular/common/src/facade/lang';


export interface HistoryState {
    state: any;
    title: string;
    path: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class HiddenLocationStrategy extends LocationStrategy {
    private baseHref: string = '';
    private pathHistory: HistoryState[] = [];
    private poppedPathHistory: HistoryState[] = [];

    constructor(
        private platformLocation: PlatformLocation,
        @Optional() @Inject(APP_BASE_HREF) baseHref?: string
    ) {
        super();

        if (isPresent(baseHref)) {
            this.baseHref = baseHref;
        }
    }

    onPopState(fn: LocationChangeListener): void {
        this.platformLocation.onPopState((ev: PopStateEvent) => {
            let backward = this.pathHistory.find((item) => item.state.uid === ev.state.uid);
            let forward = this.poppedPathHistory.find((item) => item.state.uid === ev.state.uid);

            if (backward) {
                this.navigateBack();
            } else if (forward) {
                this.navigateForward();
            }

            fn(ev);
        });
        //this.platformLocation.onHashChange(fn);
    }

    getBaseHref(): string {
        return this.baseHref;
    }

    path(): string {
        return this.pathHistory.length > 0
            ? this.pathHistory[this.pathHistory.length - 1].path
            : '';
    }

    prepareExternalUrl(internal: string): string {
        return Location.joinWithSlash(this.baseHref, internal);
    }

    pushState(state: any, title: string, path: string, queryParams: string) {
        state = Object.assign({}, state, {
            uid: (new Date()).valueOf()
        });

        this.pathHistory.push({
            state: state,
            title: title,
            path: path
        });

        this.platformLocation.pushState(state, title, this.prepareExternalUrl(''));
    }

    replaceState(state: any, title: string, path: string, queryParams: string) {
        this.platformLocation.replaceState(state, title, path);
    }

    forward(): void {
        this.platformLocation.forward();
    }

    back(): void {
        this.platformLocation.back();
    }

    private navigateForward() {
        this.pathHistory.push(this.poppedPathHistory.pop());
    }

    private navigateBack() {
        this.poppedPathHistory.push(this.pathHistory.pop());
    }
}
```